# DECRYPT a hexadecimal string using AES 128 bit in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, encryption, oracle11g

I have executed below function to convert my string into AES 128 bit encrypted cipher text in Oracle

```
    create or replace function get_enc_val
 (
 p_in_val in varchar2,
 p_key in varchar2
 )
 return raw
 is
 l_enc_val raw(4000);
 begin
 l_enc_val := dbms_crypto.encrypt
 (
 src => utl_i18n.string_to_raw (p_in_val, 'AL32UTF8'),
 key => utl_i18n.string_to_raw (p_key, 'AL32UTF8'),
 typ => dbms_crypto.encrypt_aes128 +
 dbms_crypto.chain_cbc +
 dbms_crypto.pad_zero
 );
 return l_enc_val;
 end;
```

When i run select get_enc_val('1234','1234567890ghjkle') from dual; it's working fine and giving me the cipher text but when i want to decrypt it using below function i am getting error "ORA-01465: invalid hex number"

```
create or replace function get_dec_val
 (
 p_in_val in RAW,
 p_key in RAW
 )
 return VARCHAR2 
 is
 l_enc_val VARCHAR2(4000);
 begin
 l_enc_val := dbms_crypto.DECRYPT
 (
 src => utl_i18n.RAW_TO_CHAR (p_in_val, 'AL32UTF8'),
 key => utl_i18n.RAW_TO_CHAR (p_key, 'AL32UTF8'),
 typ => dbms_crypto.encrypt_aes128 +
 dbms_crypto.chain_cbc +
 dbms_crypto.pad_zero
 );
 return l_enc_val;
 end;
```

```
 select get_dec_val('12519D97D5299702A284F2E530F58A20','1234567890ghjkle') from dual
```

Can anyone help me to understand the issue?

Comment: `src` and `key` in decrypt should be RAW, not some char type

Comment: If i change both src and key to RAW then i am getting error "Invalid hex value'. So i tried changing the src => p_in_val and key => utl_i18n.string_to_raw (p_key, 'AL32UTF8') but now decrypted output is completely different than the input text

Comment: @VivekSingh Check the below answer. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following way and it is working.

Encryption:

```
 create or replace function get_enc_val
     (
     p_in_val in varchar2,
     p_key in varchar2
     )
     return raw
     is
     l_enc_val raw(4000);
     begin
     l_enc_val := dbms_crypto.encrypt
     (
     src => utl_raw.cast_to_raw(p_in_val),
     --You can also use: src => utl_i18n.string_to_raw (p_in_val, 'AL32UTF8') 
     key => utl_raw.cast_to_raw(p_key),
     typ => dbms_crypto.encrypt_aes128 + dbms_crypto.chain_cbc + dbms_crypto.pad_zero
     );
     return l_enc_val;
     end;
    /
```

Decryption:

```
create or replace function get_dec_val
 (
 p_in_val in RAW,
 p_key in varchar2
 )
 return VARCHAR2 
 is
 l_enc_val VARCHAR2(4000);
 begin
 l_enc_val := dbms_crypto.DECRYPT
 (
 src => p_in_val, -- No Need to convert ROW to CHAR.
 key => utl_raw.cast_to_raw(p_key),
 typ => dbms_crypto.encrypt_aes128 + dbms_crypto.chain_cbc + dbms_crypto.pad_zero
 );
 return l_enc_val;
 end;
/
```

And then select Decrypted string using

> cast_to_varchar2

```
select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(get_dec_val('12519D97D5299702A284F2E530F58A20','1234567890ghjkle')) from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with your `decrypt` function and how you call the `function`.

Your `decrypt` function should look like this:

> ```
> SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_DEC_VAL (
>   2      P_IN_VAL   IN         RAW,
>   3      P_KEY      IN         RAW
>   4  ) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
>   5  BEGIN
>   6      RETURN UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(
>   7          DBMS_CRYPTO.DECRYPT(
>   8              SRC => P_IN_VAL, -- this is already RAW data type, should not be changed to char
>   9              KEY => P_KEY, -- this is already RAW data type, should not be changed to char
>  10              TYP => DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES128 + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_ZERO)); -- it returns RAW data type so converted to varchar2 using UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2
>  11  END;
>  12  /
> ```

**Now let's test it:**

> ```
> SQL> SELECT
>   2      GET_DEC_VAL(
>   3          '12519D97D5299702A284F2E530F58A20', 
>   4          UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW('1234567890ghjkle', 'AL32UTF8')) AS DECRYPTED_VAL
>   5  FROM DUAL; -- ^^ converterd the key to RAW data type
>
> DECRYPTED_VAL
> --------------
> 1234
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!